# Name for a data preparation technique for classification

Tags: classification, data-preprocessing

Say I am looking to classify an object based on certain patterns of events that occur. If I want to use classification, one easy way to do it is to divide the time up into some unit (like per day), and count the various events of various kinds and then use those variables as my feature, then classify object-days.

This seems to be a fairly common and straightforward technique - my question is does it have a name?

I would also be interested in other related techniques or pointers to literature around this.

Comment: This is impossible to answer without knowing about the data and the ultimate goal.

Comment: Which question is impossible to answer? Whether or not this technique has a name? Or if there are related techniques, or literature about it?

Comment: Whether the technique is appropriate to the task.

Comment: That was not the question I asked.

Comment: My ultimate goal is to be able to talk about what I do using language that is commonly used by other practitioners. I see that this is a common method. I do not recall seeing it referred to by a name, but describing it again and again is rather awkward. So I asked (rather clearly I though) if this method has a name.

"No, to my knowledge" for example would be an informative answer, especially from a high-rep user like you.

Comment: Then I guess the general name for this possibly information losing method is data reduction.  Aggregation also comes to mind.